# BIOS battery drains withing 1 week

Tags: bios, battery, desktop

I have a Compaq presario sr1210IL desktop PC.
I recently refurbished the PC by adding new RAM, BIOS battery.
It has been working fine, but one thing I noticed is that my bios battery drains so quickly (Withing 1 week!!).
Can somebody tell me whether it is an issue with the motherboard or bios or virus or some other components etc?

Comment: Replace battery, maybe it was wrong. And only if another battery would drain within a week too then search the reason in another component. PS. Be sure your motherboard needs in a battery, not in an accumulator...

Comment: I tried with 2 batteries. I am using Cr2032 Batteries. My motherboard is asus kelute. https://www.manualslib.com/manual/637819/Asus-A7v8x-La-Kelut.html

Comment: I dont know about accumulator. I will check and see